# Push notifications no longer working?

Tags: notifications, apns, ios

Push notifications for any app are no longer working with my home WiFi network. I'm running an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.2. I tried 5223 port forwarding and even disabled my router's firewall.

Strangely, they do work when I use public WiFi. Any idea?

Comment: If you are getting push notifications on other networks, you can rule out the update to 4.3.2 as well as the phone. You might try deleting the network settings for your home network, first on the phone and then investigate the router for failure / software changes.

Comment: What type of Router/Broadband Modem are you using?  Also, what, if any security settings are you using above and beyond basic WAP/WEP settings?

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your router and add in the security features you use, one by one, until you see what 'breaks' push notifications.